# Qt how to create bitmap from data from QVector and show it on widget?

Tags: c++, qt, bitmap, qvector

I'm wondering how I can create bitmap from my data and show it on my widget.

I have QVector vector, which is vector of some points to draw chart. How I can repaint it on my widget but with using QBitmap? I don't want draw simply on widget, I prefer pass the pixmap to widget, just to show it.

How can I do this?

My code:

```
QPainter painter(pixMap);
painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::black, 2));
painter.drawPolyline(this->data.data(), this->data.size());
painter.drawLine(QPointF(5,5),QPointF(50,50));

setPixmap(*pixMap);
```

Here is my sample code. Why it's not working? I can't see anything on widget.

[image]

I have widget class

```
class Widget : public QLabel
{
  public:
    Widget(QVector<QPointF> * data);
    ~Widget();
  protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent * event);
  private:
    QVector<QPointF> data;
    QPixmap *pixMap;
};
```

In constructor I have

```
 Widget::Widget(QVector<QPointF> * data){
   pixMap = new QPixmap(300,300);
   pixMap->fill(Qt::red);
 }
```

And in paintEvent

```
void Waveform::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
  QPainter painter(pixMap);
  painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::white, 2));
  painter.drawPolyline(this->data.data(), this->data.size());
  painter.drawLine(QPointF(5,5),QPointF(50,50));
  setPixmap(*pixMap);
}
```

If I replace `QPainter painter(pixMap)` with `QPainter painter(this)`, I can see my chart. But I want to use pixmap.

Comment: QBitmap uses for masks etc, it has color0 and color1, what do you want exactly, create mask for pixmap or just draw a plot or something else?

Comment: I want to draw a plot but not on the widget directly. I want to in some way bitmap from my data, and then show the bitmap on QLABEL.

Comment: Why bitmap? Bitmap is a mask with 2 colors, pixmap is better, you can use different colors and draw lines and points. QPixmap.

Comment: please see code below

Comment: Your code looks fine, if data() returns really correct data, then my answer should be a solution, point me if it is not. Also, don't add your code as answer, just edit your question (click Edit)

Comment: But I can't see any color of pixmap. It's always white

Comment: I deleted my answer, because is not useful, to be honest, I blind now, so I can't tell you something useful without full code of Widget: public QLabel . If you can post here your code, then do this, if something forbids you to do this, then sorry, I can't help.

Comment: Ok, I undelete my answer and it contains solution of your problem, check it plaese. Also I edited your question and added all what you include in your answer. I recommend you delete your answer, because rules of SO and community don't like it, you can get downvote

Comment: I don't see you answer. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think so, but I wasn't sure without full code, now I am absolutely sure. You should do standard processing of paintEvent. So try this:

```
void Waveform::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e)
{
    static const QPointF points[3] = {
        QPointF(10.0, 80.0),
        QPointF(20.0, 10.0),
        QPointF(80.0, 30.0),
    };
    QPainter painter(pixMap);
    painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::black, 2));
    painter.drawPolyline(points, 3);
    painter.drawLine(QPointF(5,5),QPointF(50,50));
    setPixmap(*pixMap);
    QLabel::paintEvent(e);//standard processing
}
```

But I think that you don't need paintEvent at all, then you can totally remove paintEvent from your class or do

```
void VertLabel::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e)
{
    QLabel::paintEvent(e);//in this case you don't need paintEvent at all, remove it from cpp and header files
}
```

and in constructor:

```
   pixMap = new QPixmap(300,300);
   pixMap->fill(Qt::red);
   this->resize(300,300);
   static const QPointF points[3] = {
       QPointF(10.0, 80.0),
       QPointF(20.0, 10.0),
       QPointF(80.0, 30.0),
   };
   QPainter painter(pixMap);
   painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::black, 2));
   painter.drawPolyline(points, 3);
   painter.drawLine(QPointF(5,5),QPointF(50,50));
   setPixmap(*pixMap);
```

Comment: It didn't help. My widget is always white, never change the color. 

I have a widget with QLabal generalization.

class Widget: public QLabel

My code is in overloaded paintEvent function. What can be wrong here

Comment: I talked about pixmap, not a widget, show screenshot, what did you get? Black screen, white screen, or just standard widget color, what exactly?

Comment: Please see image above

Comment: Ok so I think that the QLabel::paintEvent(e); made a trick. But why? I don't really understand why I need to call paintEvent from QLabel if my Widget derived from QLabel.

Comment: @Tatarinho In your derived class you reimplement paintEvent, so in your event there are a few lines of code, but QLAbel has more things inside paintEvent, and you need this things if you want use setPixmap. So in your case QLabel::paintEvent(e);  is necessary